# Journaling software with sections to be filled out each day

Tags: note-taking, journal

I'm looking for some sort of journaling/diary software which lets me define different sections that can be filled out each day.

For example, I might want to have a "Gym log" section (free form), a "Food log" (free form or sub-divided), a "Did I remember to do this?" list of checkboxes, a "measurements" section with pre-defined fields, and so on.  Each day would then have the same set of sections based on this template.

I've looked at what's out there, but everything I've found falls into two categories: Arbitrary entries (add as many entries per day as you want, no inherent structure) or daily entry (one entry per day, no sections).  I want something which will have the same sections each day *even if they're blank*.

Other notes:

- Ideally, it would be OSX-compatible, but Windows-only is tolerable.  Web-based is fine too.
- Syncing/accessibility on an iOS device is a major plus, but not a requirement.  Conversely, an iOS-only app would be acceptable, but not ideal.
- Free is great, but I'm willing to pay for sufficiently useful software.  Ideally, the price would be less than $30, but that's a pretty soft limit. <sub>(That said, money is finite, so the more expensive it actually is, the less likely I am to actually buy and use it)</sub>
- Password protection is irrelevant (aside from account credentials, if necessary)
- I'd love to have the ability to have alternate views based on sections, such as "show me the 'gym' section from every day".

Answer (score 1):

Check out Life Journal (https://beautifullifeapps.com/pages/life-journal) - which is currently for Windows. Journal app that allows for both free form writing as well as the use of templates. Comes with some pre-defined templates but also has a template editor that you can use to create your own templates. You can also attach images, tag entries, mark favorites, search, etc. Data is password protected as well as encrypted.

[image: Beautiful UI - comes with multiple skins/themes]

Answer (score 0):

I like the thought of digital journals, but I also like writing (an analog journal).

Lately I've been looking at Bullet Journals, around since about 2013, with a **host** of YouTube videos to get one started.

Yet I thought that not being able to search was a real drawback.

It turns out that Moleskin and Evernote are partnering to allow you to take photos of your pages and make them search-able -- a nice amalgam of the two approaches to journaling.

See [Moleskine at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01ERPLSBI) (I am not connected with any of the products or services mentioned).

See also [A visual-note-taking, mind-mapping utility](http://www.thebrain.com/) for *only* the digital experience. Numerous tutorials are freely available.

Good luck ... cheers, drl